# Does .so file change any types?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I'm using `pmemobj_create` from https://pmem.io/pmdk/manpages/linux/v1.4/libpmemobj/pmemobj_open.3 in my own code foo.c. It takes arguments `PMEMobjpool *pmemobj_create(const char *path, const char *layout, size_t poolsize, mode_t mode)`. When compile `foo.c` directly to `foo.o`, than link `foo.o` with `test.o`, everything works fine. 
I used the following compilation commands.

```
gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o
gcc test.o foo.o -o test
```

But when I compile `foo.c` to `libfoo.so` first, using

```
gcc -c -fPIC foo.c -o foo.o
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

Then link it with test.o,
the compilation succeeded, but at execution, the execution of the function `pmemobj_create` fails with an error indicates `Invalid argument`. My assumption is that the way I compile `foo.c` might be wrong, which causes the arguments I passed into `pmemobj_create` to be invalid. But how can I fix it? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `When compile foo.c directly` Could you show the command how do you do that? `Then link it with test.o` Could you show the command?

Comment: Please provide some [mre] in your question, so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62279873/edit) it to improve it.

Comment: Show more C source code, and all the compilation and linking commands. **Your question is unclear**

Answer (score 1):

> Does .so file change any types?

If you think of MIME types, no. Check with [file(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html). But in C++ code compiled by [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), type information is encoded by [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) (and some C-callable libraries are coded in C++). So use `extern "C"` (for public function names in plugins) as suggested in the [C++ dlopen mini-howto](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/).

A shared library (or  `*.so` file) does not contain a lot of type information. Read about the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format. At link time, there is just a difference between data and code, and both named functions and data have a name, an alignment, a size (in bytes) an not much more type information (except being data, function and their segment). Check with [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html), [objdump(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html), [nm(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html).

On Linux: read [*how to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) then compile your plugin [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -fPIC -O1 foo.c -shared -o libfoo.so`.

Perhaps you should also append `-lpmemobj` to the above `gcc` command.

Learn to use the [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) debugger. Your main program needs to be compiled [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then [linked](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) with `-rdynamic -ldl` passed to `gcc`

Use also not only [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) but also [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html), [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) to understand what is going on at runtime.

Read more about [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8html), [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html).